# How to add conditionals to user input in App Scripts with while loops?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I made a selectBox which had its range of values from  a Google Sheet Column. I also want to take an Integer input value from the user and then write this value in a specific cell according to option taken from selectBox. The html link does not show the integer response box. Is it possible to do the above plan in a while loop? Would appreciate any ideas and correction of code

```
function doGet() {


  var ap = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Gsheet URL here");

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var user = ui.prompt("Put down a number");
  var result = result.getSelectedButton();

  var sheet = ap.getSheetByName("lv");
  var values = sheet.getRange("A2:A10").getValues();
  var options = values.map(function(row)
{
  #To show show the selected option??
  var  item  = options.getSelecteditem();

  
  if (item === A3)
      {
      var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
       var a1 = cell.getA3Notation();
       var val = cell.getValue();
       SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Ur value is  "+a1+" value is "+val);
      }
      
  
   {
    return '<option value="' + row[0] + '">' + row[0] + '</option>';
  });
  var html = '<form onSubmit="handleSubmit(this)">  Type of Cuisine' + options.join('') + '</select></form>';
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
}
```

Comment: Your script has some syntactic errors.  You are missing a `{` after `function(row)` and you are using options inside the function but it is the return array of map.  So I'm not sure what your doing.  Also `options.getSelecteditem()`, what is that?  Also you can get the number using `ui.prompt(title,prompt, buttons)`

Comment: Class Range does not have a method getA3Notation(),  You should atleast save your script before posting here because the script editor with run a syntax check on save so that you can correct errors of which you seem to have a surplus of.

Comment: @TheWizEd.. Made the change.TNX.
options.getselectedItem is to show the selected option from the list

Comment: @Cooper.. 
Should I seperate functions and recall them instaed?

Comment: If you are running a webapp then using the UI in the doget will most likely not work because webapps normally don't open spreadsheets in user interface mode ... only users can do that.  So I'm guessing that will cause an error in your runtime.

Comment: I think it's okay just to correct them

Comment: A3 is undefined

Comment: Does any of your script work? I doubt it.  values is an array of values either number, text, date.  And it is the return value of map which used `options.getSelecteditem()`.  Where is `getSelecteditem()` defined?  And how can you use the return value of the callback funtion in the function?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. This means that beside adding the code you should include enough details for others to reproduce the problem, including but not limited to, the steps you follow to run the script, how do you figured out that "The html link does not show the integer response box. ", if any, the textual error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using an Html Dialog to Control User Inputs

Not sure what you wanted so here's a complete example I whipped up for you.

Code.gs:

```
function processInput(obj) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const [min,max,locs] = sh.getRange('B1:B3').getValues().flat();
  Logger.log('min: %s max: %s locs: %s',min,max,locs)
  const lA = locs.split(',');

  if(obj.int > max) {
    obj.msg = "Too High Try Again";
    return obj;
  } else if (obj.int < min) {
    obj.msg = "To Low Try Again";
    return obj;
  } else if (!~lA.indexOf(obj.loc)) {
    obj.msg = "Invalid Location";
    return obj;
  } else {
    sh.getRange(obj.loc).setValue(obj.int);
    obj.msg = "Complete";
    return obj;
  }
}
```

Following function Launches the dialog:

```
function launchInputDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah1'),"Enter Input");
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>input {margin: 2px 5px 2px 0;}</style>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="in1" placeholder="Enter an integer" />
    <br /><input type="text" id="in2" placeholder="Enter a location" />
    <br /><input type="button" value="Process" onClick="processinput();" />
  </form>
  <div id="msg"></div>
  <script>
    function processinput() {
      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = '';
      let v1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('in1').value);
      let v2 = document.getElementById('in2').value;
      let obj = {int:v1,loc:v2,msg:''};
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(robj => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(robj))
        if(robj.msg == "Complete") {
          document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = `Value: ${robj.int} Location: ${robj.loc} Try Again`;
          document.getElementById("in1").value = '';
          document.getElementById("in2").value = '';
        } else {
          document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = robj.msg;
        }
      })
      .processInput(obj);


    }
  </script>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Short Demo:

[image]

#### This version uses a `<select>` tag to allow the user to determine where the data will be loaded

GS:

```
function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log(e.postData.contents);
  Logger.log(e.postData.type);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  sh.getRange(data.loc).setValue(data.id)
}

function sendData(obj) {
  const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  const params = { "contentType": "application/json", "payload": JSON.stringify(obj), "muteHttpExceptions": true, "method": "post", "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
}

function displayError(msg) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(msg);
}

function launchMyDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah1'), 'My Dialog');
}

function getSelectOptions() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Options');
  var rg = sh.getDataRange();
  var vA = rg.getValues();
  var options = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < vA.length; i++) {
    options.push(vA[i][0]);
  }
  return vA;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="txt1" name="id" placeholder="Enter Numbers only"/>
      <select id="sel1" name="loc"></select>
      <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="processForm(this.parentNode);" />
    </form>
    <script>
      function processForm(obj) {
        console.log(obj.id.value);
        if(obj.id.value.match(/[A-Za-z]/)) {
          google.script.run.displayError("Invalid Characters Found in id field");
        } else {
          google.script.run.sendData(obj);
        }
      }
      window.onload = function() {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(updateSelect)
        .getSelectOptions();
      }
      function updateSelect(vA) {
          var select = document.getElementById("sel1");
          select.options.length = 0; 
          for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
            select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
          }
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is a really helpful example. Really appreciate  it... Just need to work around updating cell with that int value according to user option from a selectBox..

Thank you

Comment: I don't really know what you are  talking about when you say `Just need to work around updating cell with that int value according to user option from a selectBox`

Comment: 1-User is gonna  respond with int value(to input box--like the one u provided)
2-User is also Gonna choose an option from a SelectBox(Which has a range of options from a G sheet Column).
3-After I want to manipulate the user response to that input value in specific cells..I will choose the cells according to the user option from that selectBox which had its options from a Google Sheet Column...
I have a set up a specific organization or system for the sheet..

 

Hope this explains it

Comment: Turned out creating such system where user can respond from external limk(HTML) is difficult... So I turned to Python\ Tkinter GUIs and Pygsheets..Still not able to respond from external link(html) but Python is better in terms of diverse functions and  being familiar with code

Comment: So do you want to have the `<select>` determine to which cell the value is written too?

Comment: I added a select which is loaded from the contents of a spreadsheet

Comment: Hi @Cooper
Thank you so much for the correction and new code.
Yes I want <select> (Chosen option from Spreadsheet) to determine to which cell the input value is written to and then I can do some arithmetic operations with the cell and other cells that are related(Mainly adding the input value to current value of corresponding cell based choices)